# How can I get a list of all tables and views used in the from clause of tables and views in a MYSQL Database?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I'm trying to determine what tables and views are used for all tables and views in a MYSQL database. For example I need to see that:

```
table A uses view B
table A also uses table C   
table C uses table D
table C also uses view X
```

I know I have to do a query against the information_schema and join it against another query of the information_schema, but don't know what those queries should be.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of the tables and views used in the FROM clause of views for a given database you could use:

```
SELECT CONCAT('`', v.table_schema,'`.`', v.table_name,'`') AS 'view', 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' `', t.table_schema,'`.`', t.table_name, '`')) AS 'tables' 
FROM information_schema.tables t
JOIN information_schema.views v
  ON (v.view_definition REGEXP CONCAT('`', t.table_schema, '`.`' , t.table_name, '`') = 1)
WHERE v.table_schema = 'sakila'
GROUP BY 1;
```

MySQL rather helpfully expands the table names used when storing the view definition to include the schema name as well and then escapes the lot with backticks. By matching against this full string rather than just the table name we can eliminate matches against partial strings, column names and aliases that happen to match as well.

I'm assume that when you say "table C uses table D" in your question you are referring to a foreign key relationship between the two. You can get this data from `information_schema.key_column_usage`.

e.g.

```
SELECT CONCAT('`', table_schema, '`.`', table_name, '`') AS 'table', 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(' `', referenced_table_schema, '`.`', referenced_table_name, '`')) AS 'referenced table(s)' 
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage 
WHERE 1 = 1
AND table_schema = 'sakila'
AND referenced_column_name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1;
```